# C Exta Values of String

Tags: c

I m trying to parse between : : things like :amf aa :amfe.But some extra values added to string.In the code everything is more specific

```
char *aparse(char *str,char *a1,char *a2)
{
    char *aa;
    char *cr = strstr(str,a1);
    char *sr =  strstr(str,a2);
    int first = cr-str;
    int second =  sr-str;
    int ftag = first+5;
    int stag  = second-1;
    long wtag = stag-ftag;
    int i=0;


    aa =  malloc(wtag);


    for (i=0; i<wtag; i++)
    {
        aa[i] = str[ftag];

        ftag++;

    }


printf ("%s\n",aa);
return aa;
}
```

This is my parser code.

```
    char *aa = ":amf gosadaogle :amfe :fil doc :file";
char *music = aparse(aa,":amf",":amfe");
char *o = aparse(aa,":fil",":file");
```

This is the way how i call function.But one of the string is comes with extra characters which comes from place i dont know.Its like o = doc but music = gosadaogle .I make aa array
and the extra values are disappear.But i want do it malloc.How can i solve it

I m sorry i think i can't tell my problem clearly

This will explain

i m trying to extract values between :amf and :amfe .While i m extracting with aparse some extra characters added to music or o variable

Comment: please specify more clearly what you want the code to do

Comment: i m trying to extract values between :amf and :amfe .While i m extracting with aparse some extra characters added to music or o variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell I never see that you are adding a zero termination to the string. In C you have to place a '\0' at the end of the string to mark it's end. (That's also why the allocated size for a string must be number of characters + 1). If you don't have such a end marker you'll get random garbage after the string.

I guess the calculation of wtag is to calculate the length of the resulting string, so there you got your problem with the missing "+1" size. Another issue is that you are offsetting the `ftag` value with an "arbitrary" number of '5' while it should depend on `strlen(a1)`.

There are a few other notes I'd like to add:

1. The code you use to invoke the parser is likely to give you a
   warning about converting a `const char *` to a non-const value. This
   is because `char *aparse(char *str,char *a1,char *a2)` makes the
   compiler think that you want to be able to modify the passed
   strings. You should change this to `char *aparse(const char *str,
   const char *a1, const char *a2)` as you are not going to modify any
   of the parameters.
2. Instead of coding the copy function yourself you can use strncpy()
   to copy the string this will speed up the copy process for longer
   strings. Also take care that you add a '\0' after copying the string
   as strncpy not necessarily does this for you.
3. You should check whether `strstr` returned NULL or not because this can happen in case `a1` or `a2` are not present in `str`.

Comment: thank you i forget this.you are very helpful with your notes.

Comment: @user2102021 You're welcome. Forgot just one important note: You should check the return values of strstr before calculating with it. In case the string you are looking for cannot be found strstr returns NULL so if you don't check for this you'll be screwed. I'll add this to my answer too.